# Notepad to HashMap- Java

Tags: java, hashmap, notepad

I wrote a small program that reads from a text file based on supplied user type Admin/ Customer and prints single id and password, which is working. Code below

```
public class TextReader {

    //A method to load properties file
    public static Properties readProp() throws IOException {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\config.text");
        prop.load(file);

        return prop;
    }

    //Read the file using method above
    public static void getUser(String userType) throws IOException {
        Properties prop = readProp();
        String userName=prop.getProperty(userType+ "_User");
        String userPassword=prop.getProperty(userType+ "_Psd");

        System.out.println(" The user is " + userName + " password " + userPassword);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        getUser("Admin");
    }
}
```

Test file:

```
Admin_User=jjones@adm.com
Admin_Psd=test123


Cust_User=kim@cust.com
Cust_Psd=test123
```

I wanted to modify it so that I can now add those to a HashMap. So I removed the userType argument

```
public static void getUser() throws IOException {
        Properties prop = readProp();
        String userName = prop.getProperty("_User");
        String userPassword = prop.getProperty("_Psd");

        HashMap<String, String> hmp = new HashMap<String, String>();
        hmp.put(userName, userPassword);

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> credentials : hmp.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(credentials.getKey() + " " + credentials.getValue());
        }

        //System.out.println(" The user is " + userName + " password " + userPassword);
    }
```

I get null null as output. I cannot think of a way to get them in HashMap, I can use some hint/help.

```
Expected output: user name, password as key value pair
jjones@adm.com test123


kim@cust.com test123
```

Comment: It's a __really__ bad idea to store customer passwords in plain text.

Comment: In the original, you use `userType+ ` in the second example you don't. Basically, there is no property called `_User` or  `_Psd.

Comment: If I use userType then I only get 1 either Admin or Customer, is there no way to read both without giving argument?

Comment: You could read the file line by line and split lines with a length > 0 on the `=` sign.

Comment: You could also do something like https://www.java2novice.com/java-collections-and-util/properties/all-keys/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert a `Properties` object to a `HashMap<String, String>`, copy all the entries:

```
HashMap<String, String> hmp = new HashMap<>();
for (String name : prop.stringPropertyNames())
    hmp.put(name, prop.getProperty(name));
```

If the properties file can contain other properties, filter while copying, e.g.

```
HashMap<String, String> hmp = new HashMap<>();
for (String name : prop.stringPropertyNames())
    if (name.endsWith("_User") || name.endsWith("_Psd"))
        hmp.put(name, prop.getProperty(name));
```

Or the same using regex:

```
Pattern suffix = Pattern.compile("_(User|Psd)$");
HashMap<String, String> hmp = new HashMap<>();
for (String name : prop.stringPropertyNames())
    if (suffix.matcher(name).find())
        hmp.put(name, prop.getProperty(name));
```